# Install keras tensorflow in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a simple Flask web app with CRUD operations and deployed in beanstalk with the below requirements.txt file

```
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
mysql==0.0.2
mysqlclient==1.4.6
SQLAlchemy==1.3.15
Werkzeug==1.0.0
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.0
```

It worked fine, and then I wrote a below function

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import os

def face_shape_model(): 
    classifier = load_model('face_shape_recog_model.h5')
    image = cv2.imread('')
    res = str(classifier.predict_classes(image, 1, verbose=0)[0])
    return {"prediction": res}
```

with including below packages in to requirments.txt file

```
keras==2.3.1
tensorflow==1.14.0
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
```

whole flask application working fine in my local environment so I zipped and deploy into **AWS elasticbeanstalk** after deployment it logged below error

```
Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0a2a8a4c5b3e56b81'. Aborting the operation.
Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
```

as mentioned above I checked my log and it shows below error

```
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

so I searched about the above error find below solution according to that  and I created yml file and added it into **.ebextension** file as below

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
```

but I still get the same error. how can I solve this or is there any wrong steps above

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't tensorflow require GPU or CUDA?

Comment: @Marcin in my local environment setup, It worked fine with above requirments.txt file

Comment: maybe try different approach. Can you login to your EB instance, and manually setup your project. This includes installing dependencies, compiling tensorflow and others. This way will be able to verify that it works, and the issue is only limited to automating the deployment.

Comment: @Marcin I tried with docker container now its works fine thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved with docker container, I created docker environment In AWS ElasticBeanstalk and deployed it, and now it works fine, below shows my config file and Dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6.8

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/flask_app/
COPY src/requirements.txt /usr/src/flask_app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/flask_app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/flask_app

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "src/app.py"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000",
      "HostPort": "80"
    }
  ]
}
```